# How to generate a matrix with circle of ones in numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, python-2.x

There are some signal generation helper functions in [python's scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html#waveforms), but these are only for 1 dimensional signal.

I want to generate a 2-D ideal bandpass filter, which is a matrix of all zeros, with a circle of ones to remove some periodic noise from my image.

I am now doing with:

```
def unit_circle(r):
    def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
        return math.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2)
    d = 2*r + 1
    mat = np.zeros((d, d))
    rx , ry = d/2, d/2
    for row in range(d):
        for col in range(d):
            dist = distance(rx, ry, row, col)
            if abs(dist - r) < 0.5:
                mat[row, col] = 1
    return mat
```

result:

```
In [18]: unit_circle(6)
Out[18]:
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Is there a more direct way to generate a `matrix of circle of ones, all else zeros`?

Edit:
Python 2.7.12

Comment: Did the current output is your desired output?

Comment: @OhadEytan Yes, but feeling a bit convoluted and would love to see other solutions. In fact, I would love to know if there are framework to generate 2-dimensional signals like those 1-D signals provided by scipy.

Comment: You should always specify your python version, because division operator works differently in Py2 and Py3, unless you import the new operator from `__future__` in Py2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a pure NumPy alternative that should run significantly faster and looks cleaner, imho. Basically, we vectorise your code by replacing built-in `sqrt` and `abs` with their NumPy alternatives and working on matrices of indices.

**Updated** to replace `distance` with `np.hypot`(courtesy of James K)

```
In [5]: import numpy as np

In [6]: def my_unit_circle(r):
   ...:     d = 2*r + 1
   ...:     rx, ry = d/2, d/2
   ...:     x, y = np.indices((d, d))
   ...:     return (np.abs(np.hypot(rx - x, ry - y)-r) < 0.5).astype(int)
   ...: 

In [7]: my_unit_circle(6)
Out[7]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Benchmarks

```
In [12]: %timeit unit_circle(100)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.7 ms per loop

In [13]: %timeit my_unit_circle(100)
1000 loops, best of 3: 480 µs per loop
```

Comment: numpy has a "distance" function already `np.hypot(x1,x2)` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hypot.html

Comment: @EliKorvigo Thanks! Your solution is indeed much cleaner and faster!

Answer (score 9):

Here's a vectorized approach -

```
def unit_circle_vectorized(r):
    A = np.arange(-r,r+1)**2
    dists = np.sqrt(A[:,None] + A)
    return (np.abs(dists-r)<0.5).astype(int)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [165]: %timeit unit_circle(100) # Original soln
10 loops, best of 3: 31.1 ms per loop

In [166]: %timeit my_unit_circle(100) #@Eli Korvigo's soln
100 loops, best of 3: 2.68 ms per loop

In [167]: %timeit unit_circle_vectorized(100)
1000 loops, best of 3: 582 µs per loop
```

Comment: It's strange, your solution is only 150 microseconds faster on my machine (~350 microseconds vs ~500 microseconds). Can you provide your machine's specs?

Comment: @EliKorvigo Well I have an old machine : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T6600  @ 2.20GHz, 4GB RAM. Still the numbers shouldn't be that close I would think.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Alright, so I ran it on ideone and it seems the vectorized version runs at `2/3rd` of your approach when I ran it on `100`, `200` and `1000` as inputs. That could be trusted I guess. Here's the ideone run : http://ideone.com/8qFAnH This is coherent with your timings.

Comment: Testing with a single iteration is not a nice thing to do, so I reran that with `timeit` http://ideone.com/MpGi6c. Your solution is indeed 30% faster

Comment: I wonder, what makes it run almost 5 times slower on your machine.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Yeah using that `timeit` was a better idea, as I wasn't able to figure out on how to use it in a script. I always use `%timeit` from ipython console.

Answer (score 0):

[result of code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8go4.png)

```
def gen_circle(img: np.ndarray, center: tuple, diameter: int) -> np.ndarray:


  
    """
        Creates a matrix of ones filling a circle.
    """

    # gets the radious of the image
    radious  = diameter//2

    # gets the row and column center of the image
    row, col = center 

    # generates theta vector to variate the angle
    theta = np.arange(0, 360)*(np.pi/180)

    # generates the indexes of the column
    y = (radious*np.sin(theta)).astype("int32") 

    # generates the indexes of the rows
    x = (radious*np.cos(theta)).astype("int32") 

    # with:
    # img[x, y] = 1
    # you can draw the border of the circle 
    # instead of the inner part and the border. 

    # centers the circle at the input center
    rows = x + (row)
    cols  = y + (col)

    # gets the number of rows and columns to make 
    # to cut by half the execution
    nrows = rows.shape[0] 
    ncols = cols.shape[0]

    # makes a copy of the image
    img_copy = copy.deepcopy(img)

    # We use the simetry in our favour
    # does reflection on the horizontal axes 
    # and in the vertical axes

    for row_down, row_up, col1, col2 in zip(rows[:nrows//4],
                            np.flip(rows[nrows//4:nrows//2]),
                            cols[:ncols//4],
                            cols[nrows//2:3*ncols//4]):
    
        img_copy[row_up:row_down, col2:col1] = 1

 
    return img_copy

center = (30,40)
ones = np.zeros((center[0]*2, center[1]*2))
diameter = 30

circle = gen_circle(ones, center, diameter)
plt.imshow(circle)
```